# problem in getting gps coordinates in android 2.1(Found Answer)

Tags: android, gps, android-emulator

I am having a problem in getting GPS coordinates in 2.1.

The code i am using right now is working well in 1.6 but when i test
this same apk in 1.6 device is showing null values

please help me to find a way to work with 2.1 devices also

Here is my code.

```
public class GpsLocator {

   private static String PROVIDER="gps";
   private LocationManager myLocationManager=null;

   public GpsLocator(Context context) {
      myLocationManager=(LocationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
   }

   public void myOnresume() {
      myLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(PROVIDER, 0,   0, onLocationChange);
   }

   public void myonPause() {
       myLocationManager.removeUpdates(onLocationChange);
   }

   public double getLatitude() {
      Location loc=myLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(PROVIDER);
      if (loc==null) {
         return(0);
      }
      return(loc.getLatitude());
   }

   public double getLongitude() {
      Location loc=myLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(PROVIDER);
      if (loc==null) {
         return(0);
      }

      return(loc.getLongitude());
   }

   LocationListener onLocationChange=new LocationListener() {

      public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
      }

      public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
         // required for interface, not used
      }

      public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
         // required for interface, not used
      }

      public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,Bundle extras) {
         // required for interface, not used
      }
   };
}
```

in the manifest file i add permission for accessing file they are

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    LocationManager locationManager;
    String context = Context.LOCATION_SERVICE;
    locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(context);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
    criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
    criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
    criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
    criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    updateWithNewLocation(location);

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 2000, 10,   
                                           locationListener);
  }

  private final LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
      updateWithNewLocation(location);
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider){
      updateWithNewLocation(null);
    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider){ }
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, 
                                Bundle extras){ }
  };
```

Answer (score 2):

`LocationManager.getLastKnownLocation` does not guarantee that it will return a valid location. If a GPS fix hasn't been established yet, it will return null. The only reliable way to get an actual location is to use the `LocationListener` -interface. I see that you have defined a `LocationListener`, but aren't using it.

You need to modify your code so that it waits for the first call to onLocationChanged before you try to do anything with the location.

Comment: thank u tuomasR for u r suggestions,  i even tried in that also.

Comment: Any way now i got the solution

Answer (score 1):

Hi I am also facing same problem in 2.1  after i resolved like this...
it  will work for you

```
myManager = ((LocationManager) ApplicationController.getAppContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE));

myManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
            1 * 1000, 0.00001f, this);
```

Follow location changed asy method in tha u will get lat/and long

don't use bundle object over there it wont work instead of that you can use Gps Satellite class for 2.1..