# Can't get GPS coordinates

Tags: java, android, gps

G'day. I'm develop android application that uses GPS module. API version that i use is Google API8.

I'm implements LocationListener interface and setup listener

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
MyLocationListener myLocationListener = new MyLocationListener();
lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 61000, 0, myLocationListener);
```

But i can't step into void onLocationChanged(Location location) method of my listener. In logcat i see this:

```
D/GpsLocationProvider(   96): ALARM_WAKEUP
D/GpsLocationProvider(   96): startNavigating
D/libgps  (   96): qct_gps_set_qos_time_out(standalone = 2, agps = 89)
D/libgps  (   96): qct_gps_set_qos_accuracy(accuracy = 50)
D/libgps  (   96): qct_gps_set_position_mode = 1, fix_frequency = 61
D/libgps  (   96): qct_gps_start
V/libgps  (   96): DeferredActionThread pthread_cond_wait returned
V/libgps  (   96): DeferredActionThread calling send_get_position
V/AlarmManager(   96): Adding Alarm{46731390 type 2 android} ╤П╨╜╨▓ 01 04:48:29 AM
V/libgps  (   96): PD command:
V/libgps  (   96): RPC_PDSM_PD_CMD_GET_POS
V/libgps  (   96): DeferredActionThread pthread_cond_wait returned
V/libgps  (   96): PD event:
V/libgps  (   96): PDSM_PD_EVENT_BEGIN
D/libgps  (   96): report status : 1
D/GpsLocationProvider(   96): Acquiring wakelock
V/libgps  (   96): DeferredActionThread pthread_cond_wait returned
V/libgps  (   96): PD event:
V/libgps  (   96): PDSM_PD_EVENT_COMM_BEGIN
V/libgps  (   96): DeferredActionThread pthread_cond_wait returned
D/libgps  (   96): calling sAGpsStatusCallback GPS_REQUEST_AGPS_DATA_CONN
D/GpsLocationProvider(   96): mConnMgr.startUsingNetworkFeature result: 2
D/libgps  (   96): qct_agps_data_conn_failed
D/libgps  (   96): DeferredActionThread calling send_pdsm_atl_post_event PDSM_ATL_EVENT_OPEN_FAIL
D/ConnectivityService(   96): startUsingNetworkFeature for net 0: enableSUPL by 96/1000
D/ConnectivityService(   96): special network not available
V/libgps  (   96): DeferredActionThread pthread_cond_wait returned
V/libgps  (   96): PD event:
V/libgps  (   96): PDSM_PD_EVENT_GPS_BEGIN
D/libgps  (   96): report status : 3
V/libgps  (   96): DeferredActionThread pthread_cond_wait returned
V/libgps  (   96): DeferredActionThread pthread_cond_wait returned
V/libgps  (   96): DeferredActionThread pthread_cond_wait returned
V/libgps  (   96): DeferredActionThread pthread_cond_wait returned
V/libgps  (   96): DeferredActionThread pthread_cond_wait returned
V/libgps  (   96): DeferredActionThread pthread_cond_wait returned
V/libgps  (   96): DeferredActionThread pthread_cond_wait returned
V/libgps  (   96): DeferredActionThread pthread_cond_wait returned
...
```

Please, help

Comment: 'You' shouldn't be able to step into this method, it's a callback.  I assume that if you set a breakpoint on the first line of this method, it's never hit, correct?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819505/problem-in-getting-gps-coordinates-in-android-2-1found-answer to be sure that you're setting up correctly

Comment: Yes. I set breakpoint on this method, but it never stop on breakpoint

Comment: All ok. Just telphone don't catchs signal in house